# Getting "Aria.h: file not found" when installing rosaria

Tags: ros-hydro, aria, rosaria, header, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu 12.04.3, ros groovy.

I am following a ROSARIA tutorial (can't post links)
I know that it is an hydro tutorial, but I have the same issue with groovy version. Everything works well until *catkin_make* command at point 1.4.

I allways get this:

> **RosAria.cpp:3:18:** error fatal: Aria.h: No such file or directory.
> **Compilation finished.**
> **make[2]:**  [rosaria/CMakeFiles/RosAria.dir/RosAria.cpp.o] Error 1
> **make[1]:**  [rosaria/CMakeFiles/RosAria.dir/all] Error 2
> **make:[all]** Error 2 
> **Invoking "make" failed**

Where should be placed that header file? Where can I find it?

Thanx for your time! :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/91986/getting-%22aria.h:-file-not-found%22-when-installing-rosaria/) by [sucaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/7866/sucaro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-10-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) on 2013-10-17**:
Aria.h should be in /usr/local/Aria/include.   You must either use `rosdep update; rosdep install rosaria`, or install ARIA seperately.

Are you using this: http://wiki.ros.org/ROSARIA/Tutorials/How%20to%20use%20ROSARIA ? Note that the instructions for groovy and hydro are different there.

**Comment by [sucaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/7866/sucaro/) on 2013-10-17**:
Hi! thanks for your help. Yes, I am using that tutorial. "rosdep update" and "rosdep install rosaria" commands end with no errors. The problem comes with "catkin_make". I tried both groovy and hydro versions because hydro one worked fine for a co-worker. But both versions die at catkin_make step.

**Comment by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) on 2013-10-17**:
Does /usr/local/Aria/include/Aria.h exist? If so, what is printed out by catkin_make before that error?

**Comment by [sucaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/7866/sucaro/) on 2013-10-17**:
Base path: /home/marcos/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/marcos/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/marcos/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/marcos/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/marcos/catkin_ws/install

##### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/marcos/catkin_ws/build"

**Comment by [sucaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/7866/sucaro/) on 2013-10-17**:\

##### Running command: "make -j1 -l1" in "/home/marcos/catkin_ws/build"

[ 16%] Built target rosaria_gencfg
[ 33%] Building CXX object rosaria/CMakeFiles/RosAria.dir/RosAria.cpp.o
/home/marcos/catkin_ws/src/rosaria/RosAria.cpp:3:18: error fatal: Aria.h: No such file or directory

**Comment by [sucaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/7866/sucaro/) on 2013-10-17**:
MAN!! /usr/local/Aria/include dir is completely empty :S, but I got no errors  previous steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like `rosdep install rosaria` is not correctly installing the ARIA header files.  You can instead install one of these packages (use `dpkg -i ...`):

For 32-bit http://robots.mobilerobots.com/ARIA/download/current/libaria_2.8.0+ubuntu12+gcc4.6_i386.deb

For 64-bit
http://robots.mobilerobots.com/ARIA/download/current/libaria_2.8.0+ubuntu12+gcc4.6_amd64.deb

And then try `catkin_make` (without running `rosdep`).

...

If you want to help troubleshoot the underlying problem you can do this:

`sudo apt-get remove libaria-sourcedep`

`rosdep install rosaria >log 2>&1`

Then attach the `log` file here or put it on pastebin.com or send it to me reed.hedges@adept.com

---

Originally posted by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) with karma: 821 on 2013-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ruffsl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5234/ruffsl/) on 2016-02-20**:
You can find the current downloads on the ARIA wiki page here:
http://robots.mobilerobots.com/wiki/ARIA#Download_Aria

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to solve this by using `rosdep install rosaria` then going into rosaria/RosAria.cpp and editing the include line that says `#include <Aria.h>` to  `#include </usr/local/Aria/include/Aria.h>`. And also, as I had previously used `catkin_make`, I had to remove the devel and build folders from my workspace root before using it again.
It worked like a charm.

---

Originally posted by [RodriguesGabriel](https://answers.ros.org/users/18789/rodriguesgabriel/) with karma: 11 on 2014-06-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) on 2014-06-09**:
If you run `catkin_make VERBOSE=1` then it will echo the compilation commands it's actually running. Look after `Building CXX object rosaria/CMakeFiles/RosAria.dir/RosAria.cpp.o` or similar to see what `-I` flags its adding to the `c++` command, you should see `-I/usr/local/Aria/include`

**Comment by [marcobecerrap](https://answers.ros.org/users/1277/marcobecerrap/) on 2014-11-24**:
This solved my problem! Thank you :)

**Comment by [Gloria@HK](https://answers.ros.org/users/14486/gloria@hk/) on 2015-09-21**:
I did not find the .h file in /user/local/Aria.
Instead, I find the .h files in /usr/include/Aria/ . And solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

THIS IS THE EXACT SOLUTION FOR THIS QUESTION!

Once you have downloaded the Rosaria package do not run catkin_make. First you have to install Aria. That is why you are getting the error "error fatal: Aria.h: No such file or directory."

So what you have to do is:

Open Ubuntu Software Center and install the following: Shearch for Aria and click on "Show 14 technical items". Pick libraria2, libaria-dev and libraria-dev-doc.

Then do catkin_make and it will build the RosAria Package.

---

Originally posted by [End-Effector](https://answers.ros.org/users/7606/end-effector/) with karma: 162 on 2015-09-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [owengall](https://answers.ros.org/users/38158/owengall/) on 2018-11-13**:
This was my problem; I tried installing rosaria and tried compiling, then installed Aria afterwards and tried compiling rosaria again. It still wasn't finding <Aria/Aria.h>, but when I removed rosaria en reinstalled it to compile, it worked. Order matters: first Aria, then rosaria.